# Find Maximum in Venn Diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a class of 50 students, 34 students like Football, 26 students like Cricket and 16 students like Hockey. It is known that at least one student likes only Football, only Cricket and only Hockey. Similarly, at least one student likes both Football and Cricket (but not Hockey), both Football and Hockey (but not Cricket) and both Cricket and Hockey (but not Football). Further, at least one student likes all the three sports. Each student likes at least one sport.

What can be the maximum number of students who like all three sports?

My Solution through Venn Diagram was:

[image: Set Theory]

Comment: For the Cricket component of your venn diagram you have 0 for the amount that only like Cricket, but in your question is says: "It is known that at least one student likes only Football, only Cricket and only Hockey.", so shouldn't there be a minimum of a 1 instead of a 0?

Comment: Yes, sorry your correct so 1 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you could solve the problem using logical rules

h = |hockey| = 16

a = |football & !cricket & ! hockey| >= 1
b = |!football & cricket & ! hockey| >= 1
c = | football & cricket & ! hockey| >= 1

allSports = h - (min(a) + min(b) + min(c)) = 16 - 3 = 13

Comment: The answer given is 11, is 13 the correct answer ?

Comment: Given the rules were correctly posted, 13 is the correct answer